# How to navigate to a subfolder if a specified file is not present in the given folder in c#?

Tags: c#, filepath

I have a filepath,

```
string filepath = "E:\Dotnet\VSPackage1\ItemTemplates";
```

Now I want to see if a file named, "Unit.exe" is present in VSPackage1 folder, if "Unit.exe" is not present, then i have to navigate to ItemTemplates folder.

How to achieve this programatically? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: refer [Exists] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using `String.Split` and a `foreach` loop like :

```
string filepath = "E:\\Dotnet\\VSPackage1\\ItemTemplates";
string[] Folders = filepath.Split('\\');
string newPath = "";
string yourFilename = "Unit.exe";

foreach (var folder in Folders)
{
    newPath += folder + "\\";
    if (File.Exists(newPath + yourFilename))
    {
       MessageBox.Show("File found");
       break;
    }
}
```

`break` will break the `foreach` loop when file is found. Thus, the iteration would follow the sequence:

```
E:\\Unit.exe  
//Check for file, if present message will be shown "File found" and loop will be broken

E:\\Dotnet\\Unit.exe  
//Check for file, if present message will be shown "File found" and loop will be broken

E:\\Dotnet\\VSPackage1\\Unit.exe  
//Check for file, if present message will be shown "File found" and loop will be broken

E:\\Dotnet\\VSPackage1\\ItemTemplates\\Unit.exe  
//Check for file, if present message will be shown "File found" and loop will be broken
```

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe do something like the following:

```
string filepath = "E:\\Dotnet\\VSPackage1\\ItemTemplates";

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.exe");

foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
{
    if (File.Exists(filepath + @"\Unit.exe"))
    {
        //do Something
    }           
}
```